# search $.GETJSON and click does not work

Tags: jquery, json, google-maps

Ok, so am able to get the JSON from the PHP page, but when a user clicks on the `li` inside the `ul#stores` it does not run. it's like the

```
$("ul#stores").html("");
myMarkers = {"markers": data}
```

is not updating and it is not able to find it in the listing and the function below does not run. Full code at end. I am not sure if this is the best way to explain my issue.

live demo @ http://brightchoice.com.au/map.html

```
$("ul#stores li").on("click", function(event){
            var store = $(this).text();

            $("ul#stores").hide();
            $("#storeinfo").show();
            $.each(myMarkers.markers, function(i, data){

            if(store == data.name) {
                $("#storeinfo").append("<a href='map.html'><div class='greenbar'><div class='body'><div>  <span></span> </div> <p>Back</p></div></a></div><h1>"+data.name+"</h1>"+data.phone+"<br><br>"+data.address);

                //console.log(data.address);
                //console.log(data.state); // and more
             }
            });

            //searchlistings($(this).text());

        });
```

FULL CODE

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// <![CDATA[
 $(document).ready(function(){
        //set up markers
         var myMarkers = {"markers": [{"id": 1,"name": "Belconnen","url_name": "belconnen","address": "Shop 176, 3rd Floor, Westfield Shopping Centre, Benjamin Way","suburb": "Belconnen","state": "act","postcode": 2618,"country": "Australia","phone": "(02) 6251 1838","fax": "","photo": "dcddfcb5c806b2255c611bd2d108cead.JPG","text": "","display": 1,"lat": -35.238428606,"lng": 149.065917134,"email": "tc.belconnen@telechoice.com.au","dealer_code": 63014,"region_id": 3,"type": 4}]};

//set up map options
        defaultmap();

        $("a#backtomap").on("click", function(event){
        defaultmap();
            $("ul#stores").show();
            $("#storeinfo").hide();
        });


        $("button#search").on("click", function(event){

            var postcode = $("input#postcode").val();
            $.getJSON("http://vipcashback.com/system/classes/core.php?task=postcode&mycode="+postcode, function(data) {
            $("ul#stores").html("");
              listings = {"markers": data}
                $("#map").mapmarker({
                    zoom : 10,
                    center : postcode+" australia",
                    markers : listings
                });

                $.each(myMarkers.markers, function(i, data){

                });
            });
        });

        $("ul#stores li").on("click", function(event){
            var store = $(this).text();
            alert(store);
            $("ul#stores").hide();
            $("#storeinfo").show();
            $.each(myMarkers.markers, function(i, data){

            if(store == data.name) {
                $("#storeinfo").append("<a href='map.html'><div class='greenbar'><div class='body'><div>  <span></span> </div> <p>Back</p></div></a></div><h1>"+data.name+"</h1>"+data.phone+"<br><br>"+data.address);

                //console.log(data.address);
                //console.log(data.state); // and more
             }
            });

            //searchlistings($(this).text());

        });


        function defaultmap(){
            $("#map").mapmarker({
                zoom : 3,
                center : 'Australia',
                markers : myMarkers
            });
        }

});

// ]]>
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you're dynamically creating elements you should use:

```
$('ul#stores li).live('click',function(){ ...});
```

live is made so future elements can be auto binded to events.

Answer (score 0):

Going by the plugin code, it needs longitude and latitude which is missing in your JSON from the PHP page

Plugin code -

```
             if(latitude!="" && longitude!=""){
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map, 
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(latitude,longitude),
                    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                    icon: icon
                });

                // Set up markers with info windows 
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                    // Close all open infowindows
                    if (infowindow) {
                        infowindow.close();
                    }

                    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                        content: baloon_text
                    });

                    infowindow.open(map,marker);
                });
            }
        });
```